# Is this Universe scenario correct?

Tags: orbit, the-sun, black-hole, universe, solar-system

### I will try to give you my reasoning behind my scenario.

Ok I've researched and found

1. That 95 percent of the galaxy has been formed already, And the
   other 5 percent is still to come.http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2012-11/almost-all-stars-are-old-and-universe-making-hardly-any-new-ones
2. I've also found that stars can
       live up to 10 billion years.
3. the Universe is around 13 billion
   years old.
4. Much much more stars die than new stars are born and
   around 9 billion years ago the new stars being born dropped to 30
   percent.
5. If number 4 and 2 are correct almost all the stars in
   the universe should of died already.
6. Black holes are formed either by two neutron star colliding or a supernova.
7. If 5 is correct there should be a huge amount of black holes left from all
   the stars that supernovaed.
8. Black holes can consume one another and form a larger mass.
9. If our galaxy is 4.5 billion years old
   and 5 percent of the galaxy is still unformed we are almost consider
   one of the last formed galaxy and should be on the outer edge of the
   universe if we are 4.5 billion years old, So that could give us
   about 5 billion years left.
10. the references I found lean towards saying new stars hardly form.And there is a estimated 100,000,000 Black holes in the galaxy as of now.
11. A massive Black hole has to be 80 percent of our Universe  by now and slowly making its way toward our galaxy.

    *Please tell me where my info was wrong.*

**Will our solar system die of old age in 5.4 billion years or will we be consumed by the massive black hole if this scenario is plausible?**

Comment: This question makes a number of incorrect assertions. Stars are being born now. Most of the stars that exist now, will still exist in 10 billion, or even 100 billion years time. Please give some basis for your question.

Comment: All my numbers come from the authority, If I am wrong science is wrong. I know you know your stuff Rob Jeffries but I collected the information from the mainstream.So please correct these numbers and do society a favor.Unless your references are confidential to the public you may be right.

Comment: Go outside and look at Orion. See the belt? Underneath (in the northern hemisphere) is the Orion nebula, where thousands of stars have been born over the last few million years. The universe has no edge; the Sun is not a young star; no-one understands what you mean by a universal black hole, or that 93% of the universe will be dead in 1 billion years.

Comment: Sigh...instead of telling us a fairy tale, actually show your sources. There are hundreds of studies and a plethora of evidence going against half of your claims.

Comment: @Sir Cumference- I stated earlier this is a scenario composed of mainstream information. This is what the public can gather.If you are a former astronaut and have better info than the mainstream please correct these numbers and scenarios that are said to take place in this manner. The only thing I added without referencing the authority was the Universal Black Hole that was created from death of 93 percent of the stars in the Universe, What else would be lingering around? And they all eventually combined a Universal Black Hole that will devour everything including itself.

Comment: Again, don't give me a fairy tale. Just show one source that agrees with you. "Mainstream information" is extremely vague and no one knows where you learned this "mainstream information" from. Your hypotheses are also nonsense.

Comment: @t.rathjen- I just edited my question, Please point out and correct if you see a misinformation.

Comment: Can you indicate where you got the information you found? Thanks.

Comment: @HDE 226868- I just added a link to the decrease in new stars and 95% of the galaxy has already been formed. It's not nasa but they used  Japan's Subaru Telescope and the United Kingdom Infrared Telescope (UKIRT) on Mauna Kea in Hawaii, and the Telescope in Chile. And the countries involved are highly credible so I used the information. It was posted in 2012 but in astronomy discovery that should be like yesterday right? lol

Answer (score 5):

Like it was already pointed out in the comments, your assertions and assumptions are way off today's well-accepted theories. Nonetheless, I'll try to answer you questions.

```
Will our solar system die of old age in 5.4 billion years
```

Our sun is a [G-type main-sequence star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-type_main-sequence_star) with an estimated lifespan of roughly 10 billion years. Like you mentioned, it is about 4.6 billion years old and will stay in the main sequence for another 5.6ish billion years. The sun's mass is not enough to end with it's life with a supernova. Instead it will become a [red giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_giant) with a radius of about 1 AU (= astronomical unit), meaning that it will most likely devour planet earth, but won't expand further.

```
or will we be consumed by the Universal black hole?
```

I've never heard of something like an universal black hole, but it appear's to me that you might have a big misconception about black holes in general. If (for some completly unknown and unphysical reasons) the sun would all of the sudden turn into a black hole with the same mass, nothing much would change (on a cosmological scale). Planet earth's main energy input would seep away and we all would freeze to death, but gravitational, nothing would change. The planets orbits would be exactly the same and nothing would become 'consumed'. Black holes don't accrete mass (that's what I suppose you mean by consuming) due to some magical properties, but due to gravitational attraction, which is only dependent on the masses and the distance of the objects.

```
How long should it take for the 93 percent of universe to be consumed by the black hole?
```

Speaking of 93% of the universe might not make any sense. Today's measurements suggest that the curvature of space is flat ($\Omega_{tot} = 1.00 \pm 0.02$) and that yields in a possible infinite universe. Please see [$\lambda CDM-Model$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model)
and [Planck 2015 results. XIII](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01589)

Comment: @t.rathjen-If the 95 % of the universe is already formed leaving 5% left is incorrect, Can you give me a link that references a star system with a sun in the same stage as ours.Make sure it was observed and not just theory please.

Comment: I seem to miss something, but what do you mean by 'if 95 % of the universe is already formed [...]'? Do you think of the universe as a preset entity, which grows to some extent and than stays this way? If so, the observations made today suggest that you are wrong (see my links regarding the cosmological lamda-cdm-model)